# How to solve "bash: script/extension: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I need to install spree-subscriptions gem in my spree application. I used following link to install spree-subscription gem

https://github.com/BDQ/spree-subscriptions

In that if I trigger the below command i get the above error.

```
script/extension install git://github.com/BDQ/spree-subscriptions.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this plugin is for old version of `spree` which was for Rails 2.x and this command syntax is deprecated by now. I think it would be better for you to use something more up-to-date, like https://github.com/nebulab/spree-subscriptions.